# Import error on express-load dependency on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having a problem in a project i'm starting where I'm trying to use the `express-load` dependency but it is returning an error saying I can't use `require()` on my code, since I have my type set as "module" on my `package.json`. The problem is the `require` statement is being used inside the `express-load` dependency. Is there any solution known to this problem?

```
      {
        "name": "lumi-back",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "Back-end do teste da Lumi",
        "main": "index.js",
        "scripts": {
          "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
        },
        "type": "module",
        "keywords": [],
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": {
          "cors": "^2.8.5",
          "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
          "express": "^4.18.2",
          "express-load": "^1.1.16",
          "pg": "^8.11.1"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
        }
      }
```

This is my `package.json`

```
    'use strict'

    import express from 'express';
    import expressLoad from 'express-load';
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import cors from 'cors';
    //import pool from './db';

    dotenv.config();

    const app = express();
    const port = process && process.env && process.env.PORT || 5000;

    //middleware
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());

    // Carrega as rotas
    expressLoad('routes', { cwd: 'src' }).into(app);

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Express + TypeScript Server');
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
```

This is my `index.js`.

```
Node.js v18.17.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\User\Documents\Projetos\Lumi-teste\lumi-back\src\routes\ContasRoutes.js from C:\Users\User\Documents\Projetos\Lumi-teste\lumi-back\node_modules\express-load\lib\express-load.js not supported.
Instead change the require of ContasRoutes.js in C:\Users\User\Documents\Projetos\Lumi-teste\lumi-back\node_modules\express-load\lib\express-load.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Projetos\Lumi-teste\lumi-back\node_modules\express-load\lib\express-load.js:229:15
    at iterate (C:\Users\User\Documents\Projetos\Lumi-teste\lumi-back\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:131:13)
    at async.eachSeries (C:\Users\User\Documents\Projetos\Lumi-teste\lumi-back\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:147:9)
    at ExpressLoad.into (C:\Users\User\Documents\Projetos\Lumi-teste\lumi-back\node_modules\express-load\lib\express-load.js:224:9)
    at file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Projetos/Lumi-teste/lumi-back/index.js:19:39 {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting. Help please.

Comment: why even use a package that has been deprecated?  You can try using esm to enable require()